# How to get server generated file id, kinvey android

Tags: android, file-upload, kinvey

I can't find a way to get the file id in kinvey android sdk after uploading the file. The uploaderProgressListener onSuccess method returns Void. I've searched the whole sdk for it. Please help
Thanks

BTW am using kinviey android sdk 2.10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the FileMetaData object with the upload function? If not, it is described in the "Files" document for Android that is located in the Kinvey DevCenter. Take a look at the following URL.

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/files#

The section on Uploading explains it and provides an example.

If you are, in fact, using the FileMetaData object and you are still unable to find the file id then you should post the issue to the Kinvey Forum and someone from Kinvey will take a look at the problem.

Comment: Please explain what needs to be done rather than simply providing a link.

Comment: Actually the problem is with the docs as the parameter passed in the docs is Void. But the actual sdk have a FipeMetadata parameter